# Does NSURLCache really require initialization as this article indicates?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurlsession, nsurlcache

I was slightly confused by [this NSHipster article](http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/) which states that you must initialize the parameters for your cache in `appDidFinishLaunching`. I thought `NSURLCache` was automatically a part of `NSURLSession` and `NSURLConnection`.

I could have sworn I've had downloads cached before without initializing it. Is it really necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The `[NSURLCache sharedURLCache]` is set up by iOS. I just ran through the debugger and found that the initial memoryCapacity is 512,000 bytes and the initial diskCapacity is 10,000,000 bytes (for iOS 7.1).

The NSHipster article you referenced does seem to imply that you must first initialize the shared cached, but that does not appear to be true.